# Socket read and unknown length data

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am trying to write code in C, in which I want to read a data from a socket, but I do not know the length of the data coming in. I have no control over the data sender.

Is there any way to read socket read using unknown length?

The following is the code I wrote but it hangs in `read()`.

```
static void
process_command ( int fd ) {
    fprintf ( stderr, "process_command\n" );
    char *buffer = ( char * ) malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * SIZE_TO_READ );
    int n  = 0;
    while ( 1 ) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "." );
        n = read ( fd, buffer, SIZE_TO_READ );
        fprintf ( stderr, "bytes read = %d \n", n );
        if ( n <= 0 || n == -1 )
            break;
        buffer = ( char * ) realloc ( buffer, n + SIZE_TO_READ );
    }
    char * p = strchr ( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p ) *p = '\0';
    fprintf ( stderr, "-----> %s\n", buffer );
    if ( buffer ) free ( buffer );
}
```

fd in this case is FILENO_STDIN

Comment: Assigning the result of `realloc()` to the same variable as its argument is not safe, because the allocation could fail (in which case you'll leak the old buffer).  Also, your use of `strchr()` looks unsafe to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `SOCK_NONBLOCK` in call to `socket()` (or call `fcntl()` with `O_NONBLOCK` later on) to make socket operations non-blocking. This will result in `read()` call failing with either EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK (those are effectively the same) if there's no data to read (yet).

Alternatively, you may use `select()` to determine if there's any data ready to be read on a specific socket before the actual `read()` call.

Answer (score 5):

Just read by some blocks (buffers) until it returns 0 or you'll see that there is an end of the data according to the protocol.

Comment: And show an error when both the internal and virtual memory are full. Don't just crash.

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual to not have ANY way of knowing how many bytes to expect.  Most protocols have SOME way of specifying either the data length or the data terminator.  What kind of protocol are you implementing exactly?

Comment: **ALL** sensible protocols make sure the length of each message is known - either because it is fixed or because there is context to tell you how long it is.  Context might be an explicit length before the data, or it might be an end marker such as a null byte at the end of a string - but there is always a way to tell how long the data is supposed to be.

Comment: In this particular case, it looks like the protocol stops at the first newline - given that the first newline is zapped and anything after it is wholly ignored.

Comment: Don't be so sure. As an example, HTTP server may not give you 'Content-Length' header, which is quite common with badly written web apps.

Comment: If the `Content-Length` header is missing, that is not necessarily an indication of a badly written webapp.  HTTP defines multiple ways to determine the data length: the `Content-Length` header, the `chunked` coding of the `Transfer-Encoding` header, the `multipart/byteranges` content type, just to name a few.  Read RFC 2616 Section 4.4 for the full list of possibilities.